# Loop the header array with elements

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I am looking for the code which can be loop the header array with the class names but it must not include the the tag name or id. This is just to ensure if any class does not exist then the corresponding cell should be left blank and the next element should be copied.

I tried to add the header array like

```
  headers = Array("size", "features", "promo", "in store", "web")
```

But it needs to be loop with the tag name which I don't want.

also want promo (Class name is "`promo_offers`") '1st Month Free!' in row 2, the problem is this promo is given for specific cells only - hence the data is misleading and I am getting promo in 1st 4 cells and then getting error.

However, I want to copy promo for only those units where promo information is given else the cell should be blank or any other value needs to be set. Below is the code...

Please suggest how to frame the code.

```
Sub GetClassNames()

Dim html As HTMLDocument

Dim objIE As Object
Dim element As IHTMLElement
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim elements As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim result As String 'string variable that will hold our result link

Dim count As Long
Dim erow As Long

'initiating a new instance of Internet Explorer and asigning it to objIE
Set objIE = New InternetExplorer

'make IE browser visible (False would allow IE to run in the background)
objIE.Visible = True

'navigate IE to this web page (a pretty neat search engine really)
objIE.navigate "https://www.allstorageonline.com/storage-units/texas/amarillo/all-storage-hardy-115423/#utm_source=GoogleLocal&utm_medium=WWLocal&utm_campaign=115423"

'wait here a few seconds while the browser is busy
Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
count = 0

Set html = objIE.document
Set elements = html.getElementsByClassName("unit_size medium")

For Each element In elements
    If element.className = "unit_size medium" Then
        erow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        Cells(erow, 1) = html.getElementsByClassName("unit_size medium")(count).innerText

        Cells(erow, 2) = html.getElementsByClassName("promo_offers")(count).innerText
        count = count + 1      
    End If
Next element
End Sub
```

For anything i.e promo is null then the corresponding cell should be left blank the next element should be copied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all that info using xmlhttp.

I grab all the `li` elements for the boxes and loop those putting the html of each `li` into a new `HTMLDocument`. I use querySelector method of that object to get all the other items within each row using css selectors. I wrap selection in `On Error Resume Next On Error GoTo 0` to mask errors for when attempting to access elements not present e.g. some rows do not have a promo. Those entries then get left blank as requested.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, html As HTMLDocument, s As String
    Const URL As String = "https://www.allstorageonline.com/storage-units/texas/amarillo/all-storage-hardy-115423"

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
        .send
        s = .responseText
        html.body.innerHTML = s

        Dim headers(), results(), listings As Object

        headers = Array("Size", "Features", "Promo", "In store", "Web")
        Set listings = html.querySelectorAll(".li_unit_listing")

        Dim rowCount As Long, numColumns As Long, r As Long, c As Long, item As Long

        rowCount = listings.Length
        numColumns = UBound(headers) + 1

        ReDim results(1 To rowCount, 1 To numColumns)
        Dim html2 As HTMLDocument
        Set html2 = New HTMLDocument
        For item = 0 To listings.Length - 1
            r = r + 1
            html2.body.innerHTML = listings.item(item).innerHTML
            On Error Resume Next
            results(r, 1) = Trim$(html2.querySelector(".unit_size").innerText)
            results(r, 2) = Trim$(html2.querySelector(".features").innerText)
            results(r, 3) = Trim$(html2.querySelector(".promo_offers").innerText)
            results(r, 4) = html2.querySelector(".board_rate").innerText
            results(r, 5) = html2.querySelector("[itemprop=price]").getAttribute("content")
            On Error GoTo 0
        Next

        ws.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
        ws.Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
    End With
End Sub
```

---

Output:

[image]

Comment: cool man... You solved my problem quickly. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I have a small doubt.. You have entered in the header code is ".li_unit_listing" what is li in this case is it stands for tagname?

Comment: No. It is the class name.   <li class="promo_63838 li_unit_listing" </li>

Comment: it is using class name

Comment: li_unit_listing is one of the compound class names used for the li element. I didn't use li as you didn't want that.